# Where can I find the origin of specific modprobe conf option to erase it?

Tags: linux, drivers, linux-kernel, kernel-module, modprobe

When I do

```
modprobe -c |less
```

The configuration files contains:

```
options nouveau modeset=1
options bbswitch load_state=0 unload_state=1
options b43 nohwcrypt=1 qos=0
options rd md=0
options rd dm=0
options rd lvm.lv=VolGroup/lv_swap
options rd lvm.lv=VolGroup/lv_root
options rd luks=0
options rcutree rcu_idle_gp_delay=1
options nouveau modeset=0
options rd driver.blacklist=nouveau

# End of configuration files. Dumping indexes now:
```

I want to get rid of "options nouveau modeset=0", but I don't know where it's set. It's not written anywhere inside /etc/modprobe.d/ .conf files (I manually edit one .conf file to get the first modeset=1 above, but it doens't take precedence).

I can't find any modprobe option to show its configuration files and grub kernel parameters doesn't seem to be used.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: after searching the related xorg log, I found this at the top:

```
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.17.2-300.fc21.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root ro rd.md=0 rd.dm=0 rd.lvm.lv=VolGroup/lv_swap quiet SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 rhgb rd.lvm.lv=VolGroup/lv_root rd.luks=0 KEYTABLE=fr LANG=en_US.UTF-8 CONFIG_HZ=1000 rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1 nouveau.modeset=0 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau
```

The grub parameter I added may need an initramfs update.

Answer (score 0):

So the unwanted options happened to be set by some grub conf.

I override it with the following in /etc/default/grub:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="... nouveau.modeset=1"

Then I updated the initramfs img with dracut -f and it's fixed !

```
$ cat /sys/module/nouveau/parameters/modeset
$ 1
```

The driver begins to write to the device ! Now I'll have to fix a permission issue on /dev/dri/card1 ...